# Записать текст с консоли в файл, скопировать полученный файл

Tags: c#, файлы

Господа, помогите разобраться, пожалуйста. В целях обучения решил сделать небольшую программку. Она должна принимать с консоли введенный текст, после чего сохранить его в файл 9.txt. А потом этот файл побайтово копируется в файл 99.txt. 
Однако когда я начинаю это делать, то в проверке условия метод `ReadByte()` сразу же выдает значение -1 (то есть будто строчка пустая). Не могу понять, почему так. Вот код:

```
using System;
using System.IO;
class a
{
    static void Main()
    {
        FileStream fs = new FileStream(@"D:\9.txt", FileMode.OpenOrCreate);
        StringReader sr = new StringReader(Console.ReadLine());
        StreamWriter SW = new StreamWriter(fs);
        SW.Write(sr.ReadToEnd());
        SW.Flush();
        FileStream fs1 = new FileStream(@"D:\99.txt", FileMode.OpenOrCreate);
        int x = 0;
        while (true)
        {
            x = fs.ReadByte();
            if (x == -1) break;
            fs1.WriteByte((byte)x);           
        }
        fs1.Flush();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[[@polyakov_s](/users/19379/polyakov_s)](/users/19379/polyakov_s), у вас курсор находится в конце потока. Из файла уже нечего читать. Передвиньте курсор в начало файла.